# iOS method with weak versus strong

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have been reading about strong and weak when using ARC. Now I think I understand a bit better in contrast to properties.

But I have just read that I can use __weak and __strong in methods. But I'm not sure if I get this completely. How I use it is:

```
- (void)someMethod{
   __weak NSString *text = [self.textField text];
   etc...
}
```

In the example above I use weak because it will otherwise be standard strong and I do not need to have a strong pointer to it (I think). Because the textfield itself will keep it?

My question is do I understand this concept and is there even advantages using the __weak instead of default __strong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, by default `text` will be strong reference, keeping the object (`self.textField text`) alive as long as the reference is alive. But, with __weak reference, the life is of the object is determined by `self.textField`.

However, there is no real memory advantage of declaring `__weak NSString *text` (atleast in this particular case). So, I would suggest go with default behavior (*NOT* declare text as `__weak`)

```
NSString *text = [self.textField text];
```

Generally, `__weak` are recommended to avoid cyclic references e.g. `delegate`

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) id delegate;
```

Answer (score 1):

You only need to use that in special contexts. In a normal method like that you can just use 
`NSString *text`

This pointer will be strong but that's not a problem because it will be destroyed at the end of the method if nothing is using it

Answer (score 0):

declaring it as weak risks that the object 'text might be nil when you try to access it. What 'weak' means here is : if there are no 'strong' objects referring to 'text', then 'text' will be removed once 'someMethod' finishes execution.